# Organization buttons for subform

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, vba

I am trying to design a multi-use organization button.

Below the button is a subform (named ProjectQSubF), with data. Though lets only focus on 1 set of data and let's say this data is named ProjectComplete and is a boolean Y/N (checkbox) field.

I want to design a button that when you click it, it sorts all those fields by if the check is checked (yes). If you click the button again, it sorts it by the opposite state which is unchecked (no). If you keep clicking it just goes back and forth between those two states.

How would I do this?

Also, how would I do this with dates; based on closer to now and furthest away as the two states?

Answer (score 0):

create a line (or checkbox or whatever). Set it visible = false;

Use the tag value (/checked state) to hold a constant say True or False;
Name the object isSortAscending or similar;

In the click event for your button:

```
isSortAscending.Tag = (not cbool(isSortAscending.Tag)) 'switch state to the opposite
dim ss as string: ss = ProjectQSubF.Form.RecordSource  'get the existing data query 
ss = left(ss, instr(ss, "ORDER BY") - 1)               'chop off the existing sort logic
if isSortAscending.Tag = True then
    ProjectQSubF.Form.RecordSource = ss & "ORDER BY yourColumnName"
else
    ProjectQSubF.Form.RecordSource = ss & "ORDER BY yourColumnName DESC"
end if
```

Likewise with dates, DESC means newest first, ASC (or simply the absence of "DESC" - as in my code above) means oldest first.

Irrespective of whether you're using a date or true/false column, you probably wont want to limit sorting to just this column as multiple rows may well exist for any one value of the column you're using, and rows within this column will then probably appear to be unsorted, so I'd suggest appending ", nameofMainTextColumn" after the order by statements above.

Hope this helps

Comment: When I click the button, it gives me an error stating: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Sends me to this line of code: `ss = Left(ss, InStr(ss, "ORDER BY") - 1)               'chop off the existing sort logic`